# Web Api (C#, MVC) returning result JSON in local (via code and postman) but not from server(deployed)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, response, httpresponse, webapi

I have a web API which returns JSON formatted data in a file to the user. Lately users are not able to download the files as they are getting an error

"Message": "An error has occurred."

The same request if I run it through local (set up by running the code debug mode) and deploying the service in local, I am able to download the data. The download file size varies.

Is there any setting to increase the response object size in IIS, Can someone help here?

Comment: Yes, there are size settings, but they are quite generous by default. Maybe the server, or the environment it's working in prevents json "files"?

Comment: Any logged errors in Windows EventLog?

Comment: It lets users download certain JSON's...so this clears the environment part

Comment: @DanielStackenland how do I enable it in IIS?

Comment: Is on by default - look in Event Viewer -> Windows Logs -> Application

Comment: @DanielStackenland thanks for the info. There are no error logs related to my API

Comment: @NaveedQureshi Do you have any logging in any place? Like log4net or Serilog? You need to capture the exact exception when the function is hit.

Comment: @RahulSharma we dont use any loggers...I checked using event viewer but couldnt find any logs related to the API

Comment: @RahulSharma I am getting this in the log - - 443 - 10.16.52.4 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/114.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 - 500 0 0 5953

Comment: @NaveedQureshi That doesn't seem correct. What you have shown is just the device details. Have you tried to increase the `maxAllowedContentLength` in your configuration?

Comment: I fetched it form logfiles of IIS....As far as I know there is no restriction on the response size, but will surely check the maxAllowedContentLength property.